# What is the use of Armadillo-meshes and knotMeshes in open3d?

Tags: python, 3d, visualization, mesh, open3d

Since I am still a beginner with open3d and still reading the documentation. Nowhere seems to be a clear explanation for Armadillo mesh class in open3d neither for knot mesh.
Why are they different types of meshes and what are the cases one should use them?

Answer (score 1):

The reason behind the existence of these classes is explained [in their GitHub repository](https://github.com/isl-org/Open3D/blob/ac1239ed019eab4369a5257c8e94e4361aa38611/cpp/open3d/data/Dataset.h#L45-L46) as

> The Dataset classes in Open3D are designed for convenient access to "built-in" example and test data.

Example usages of Armadillo mesh include surface deformations ([ARAP](https://igl.ethz.ch/projects/ARAP/arap_web.pdf)), mesh optimization ([Laplacian Mesh Optimization](https://igl.ethz.ch/projects/Laplacian-mesh-processing/Laplacian-mesh-optimization/lmo.pdf)), skeleton extraction ([Skeleton Extraction by Mesh Contraction](http://graphics.csie.ncku.edu.tw/Skeleton/skeleton-paperfinal.pdf)), and key point detection ([Intrinsic shape signatures (ISS)](http://www.open3d.org/docs/latest/tutorial/geometry/iss_keypoint_detector.html)).

I haven't used a knot mesh before, but I believe that it is useful for applications in [knot theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knot_theory).

If you want to visualize the meshes and understand the difference better, you can do it the following way.

```py
import open3d as o3d
knot_data = o3d.data.KnotMesh()
mesh = o3d.io.read_triangle_mesh(knot_data.path)
mesh.compute_vertex_normals()  # for better visualization
o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([mesh])
```

[image: knot mesh]

```py
armadillo_data = o3d.data.ArmadilloMesh()
mesh = o3d.io.read_triangle_mesh(armadillo_data.path)
o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([mesh])
```

[image]